# Is there any way to disable DisplayAlerts only the case of overwritting file?

Tags: c++, vba, excel

I'm working on _Workbook.SaveAs API of Excel

I need to always replace if there is a file with the same name. There should not be a dialog to ask if I want to overwrite the file or not.

Now, code is:

```
app->put_DisplayAlerts(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, VARIANT_FALSE);
activeWorkbook->SaveAs(filePath,
                        fileType,
                        vtMissing,
                        vtMissing,
                        vtMissing,
                        vtMissing, 
                        Excel::xlNoChange);
app->put_DisplayAlerts(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, VARIANT_TRUE);
```

**The problem is this disables all alerts. I still want other alerts.**

For example, when users try to save a workbook with macro to ".xlsx" format, there should be an alert dialog to tell users that macro won't be included.

**Question**

Is there any way to achieve this for all version of Excel?

Thanks in advance =]

Comment: You could manually delete the file when you know you want it to be overwritten. Then just re-create it. There will never be an opportunity for an alert then.

Comment: Hi Brad, this doesn't solve all problem. For example, "D:\test.xlsx" is opened and users try to save the file as "D:\test.xlsx". This file can't be deleted and the alert still exist in this case.
Anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: It seems to me you have 4 possible scenarios when saving a file. 1. you're saving as a brand new, unused file name. 2. You're trying to save over another open file. 3. You're trying to save over the currently open file. 4. You're trying to save over another file but it's not open. Scenario 1. Is a regular Save As method (nothing special needed there). S3. Is a regular Save method. S2. Is not going to happen without error because the OS can't get control of an open file to either delete it or save over it. What you're trying to solve is S4. Which, the delete/save method would manage. Right?

Comment: Yes, but this means I have to write code to detect if it is S2 or S3 or S4, right? If it is S2, I have to switch to use Save instead of SaveAs. If it is S3, I have to manually display an alert dialog to show that the workbook won't be saved.

Comment: I think that's just the way it is. Once you write one the others will fall in line. And the general branching logic is above. I don't know how to do this in C++ but in VBA you should look into the FileSystemObject (MD Scripting Runtime). It will make this much easier.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to easily do this :(. Thank you so much Brad.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel VBA you can simply do the following:

```
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

This is the code I generally use when saving a file over an existing file.
I also now like to check in case the file I'm trying to over-write is open for editing by another user via the following Function (which I got from SO):

```
        Enum IsFileOpenStatus
                    ExistsAndClosedOrReadOnly = 0
                    ExistsAndOpenSoBlocked = 1
                    NotExists = 2
        End Enum


        Function IsFileReadOnlyOpen(FileName As String) As IsFileOpenStatus

        'ExistsAndClosedOrReadOnly = 0
        'ExistsAndOpenSoBlocked = 1
        'NotExists = 2

        With New FileSystemObject
                    If Not .FileExists(FileName) Then
                                IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 2  '  NotExists = 2
                                Exit Function 'Or not - I don't know if you want to create the file or exit in that case.
                    End If
        End With

        Dim iFilenum As Long
        Dim iErr As Long
                    On Error Resume Next
                                iFilenum = FreeFile()
                                Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
                                Close iFilenum
                                iErr = Err
                    On Error GoTo 0

        Select Case iErr
                Case 0: IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 0 'ExistsAndClosedOrReadOnly = 0
                Case 70: IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 1 'ExistsAndOpenSoBlocked = 1
                Case Else: IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 1 'Error iErr
        End Select

        End Function    'IsFileReadOnlyOpen
```

Therefore when saving a file in Excel VBA I'd have something like the following:

```
        Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    If IsFileReadOnlyOpen(myFilePathName) <> ExistsAndOpenSoBlocked Then
                               Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs myFilePathName, , , , True
                    End If
        Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: But this will disable all alerts. I just want to disable only the dialog that ask for overwritting file.
Anyway, thanks for your input :)

Comment: you only need to disable whilst saving the file & then can turn back on. Also this diabling will not then have any impact on alerts that users of the saved file receive

Comment: Ah, I put that commment before I see the rest of your msg. I have to take time to unserstand this code. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think my description is not clear enough.
I want to replace file always. I don't want the dialog to ask me if I want to overwrite file or not.
your code provide the ability to prevent saving file while it is being opened.

Comment: ok - unfortunately I cannot help you convert the above to be readable in c++ but this is the general way I go about saving workbooks using VBA

Comment: That's OK. I'm quite familiar with VBA as well. Thank you so much for your input.